# Menashe & Ephraim: Twins?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, historical-figures, miketz, twins

Were Menashe and Ephraim, sons of Yosef Hatzadik, twins?

Comment: why do you think they may have been?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seder Hadoros [puts](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24645&pgnum=64) the births of both of them in the same year (2233), and also cites [Nesiv Hayashar quoting Birkas Shmuel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19152&pgnum=24) that they were indeed twins.

Comment: Nice find, thanks! For those searching, the second citation is in the second column, 24th line.